# (In Ruby) allowing mixed-in class methods access to class constants

Tags: ruby, class, module, constants, class-method

I have a class with a constant defined for it.  I then have a class method defined that accesses that class constant.  This works fine.  An example:

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby

class NonInstantiableClass
    Const = "hello, world!"
    class << self
        def shout_my_constant
            puts Const.upcase
            end
        end
    end

NonInstantiableClass.shout_my_constant
```

My problem arises in attempting to move this class method out to an external module, like so:

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby

module CommonMethods
    def shout_my_constant
        puts Const.upcase
        end
    end

class NonInstantiableClass
    Const = "hello, world!"
    class << self
        include CommonMethods
        end
    end

NonInstantiableClass.shout_my_constant
```

Ruby interprets the method as requesting a constant from the module, rather than the class:

```
line 5:in `shout_my_constant': uninitialized constant CommonMethods::Const (NameError)
```

So, what magic tricks do you fellows have to let the method access the class constant?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby

module CommonMethods
    def shout_my_constant
        puts self::Const.upcase
    end
end

class NonInstantiableClass
    Const = "hello, world!"
    class << self
        include CommonMethods
    end
end

NonInstantiableClass.shout_my_constant
```

HTH

Comment: Well, that clears things up. I had yet to experience the :: syntax :).

Answer (score 13):

Its probably worth noting that you don't need to include modules into a metaclass.

```
class NonInstantiableClass
    Const = "hello, world!"
    class << self
        include CommonMethods
    end
end
```

Ruby has the `extend` keyword that effectively adds the modules interface to a class, e.g.

```
class NonInstantiableClass
    Const = "hello, world!"
    extend CommonMethods
end
```

You still need to ensure you're referencing the right constant using `self::Const` or `const_get`, but `extend <module>` is the better way to add those methods to the class.

Comment: Yet another helpful comment.  I've learned three things from asking one question.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is, if you just write `Const` it is evaluated on Module creation time. You have to use `Module#const_get` instead like this: `const_get(:Const)`. This is evaluated at runtime when the method is executed. So this happens in your class and not in your module.

Comment: Thanks!  That was the kind of method I was searching for, without success.