# ruby class instance variable configuration pattern

Tags: ruby, configuration

I'm trying to make a DSL like configuration for classes that include a module but to have the configured variable available to both class and instance methods seems to require littering the module with access methods. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

```
module DogMixin  
  class << self
    def included(base)
      base.extend ClassMethods
    end
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def breed(value)
      @dog_breed = value
    end

    def dog_breed
      @dog_breed
    end
  end
end

class Foo
  include DogMixin

  breed :havanese
end

puts Foo.dog_breed
# not implemented but should be able to do this as well
f = Foo.new
f.dog_breed
```

Comment: I don't fully get the question yet. What output are you expecting from `f = Foo.new; f.dog_breed = :chimp; puts Foo.dog_breed`? What constants in the class help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is a bit weird I think :)
Anyway, one way to avoid writing the accessors (the **assignment** - accessor is problematic in my eyes - especially in the given example) is to define constants, as in the example below. If however you need runtime-assignments, please edit your question (and thus render this answer invalid :) except you want to mess with runtime constant assignment, which is possible but messy).

```
module DogMixin
  # **include** DogMixin to get `Class.dog_breed`
  class << self
    def included(base)
      def base.dog_breed
        self::DOG_BREED || "pug"
      end
    end
  end

  # **extend** DogMixin to get `instance.dog_breed`
  def dog_breed
    self.class.const_get(:DOG_BREED) || "pug"
  end
end

class Foomer
  DOG_BREED = 'foomer'
  extend  DogMixin
  include DogMixin
end

f = Foomer.new
puts Foomer.dog_breed
puts f.dog_breed

# If I understand you correctly, this is the most important (?):
f.dog_breed == Foomer.dog_breed #=> true
```

It took some reading of [(In Ruby) allowing mixed-in class methods access to class constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897699/in-ruby-allowing-mixed-in-class-methods-access-to-class-constants) to get the Instance-And-Class Constant lookup from a module, but it works. I am not sure if I really like the solution though. Good question, although you could add a little detail.

Comment: Yes the example was a bit random, it's more for configuration and the example makes it look like it could be handled by inheritance (breed < dog) but thanks good answer :)